# OpenCV in cmake-based project: checking for contrib modules

Tags: c++, opencv

I have **opencv 3.0** installed (built from sources), and I include it in my **cmake**-based project with the following:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED)
```

Everything is OK with using it, but I'd like also using [contrib](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib) modules. I specified `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` when I was built **OpenCV**, and I'm sure that these modules are available (I can use them in my project), but I'd like to disable this functionality for **OpenCV** without *contrib* modules, i. e. write something like this:

```
#ifdef HAVE_OPENCV_CONTRIB
// some tasty functionality
#else
// some replacement or dummies
#endif
```

Is there any way to determine it in my *CMakeLists.txt* without adding explicit definition? I. e. I'd like to do something like this in my *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
if (DEFINED ${OPENCV_BUILD_WITH_CONTRIB})
add_definitions(-DHAVE_OPENCV_CONTRIB)
endif(DEFINED ${OPENCV_BUILD_WITH_CONTRIB})
```

Possibly there is some simple way - any defined variable after `find_package(OpenCV)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found only way to determine it by checking for some contrib module header presense in target system, i. e. something like the following:

```
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
check_include_file_cxx(opencv2/face/facerec.hpp HAVE_OPENCV_CONTRIB)
if(HAVE_OPENCV_CONTRIB)
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_OPENCV_CONTRIB)
endif(HAVE_OPENCV_CONTRIB)
```

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way of checking module nowadays is to use the `COMPONENTS` option of `find_package` :

```
find_package(OpenCV 4 COMPONENTS bgsegm)
if(OpenCV_bgsegm_FOUND)
  add_definitions("-DHAVE_BGSEGM")
endif()
```

This works both for contrib and non-contrib modules.

Comment: Yes, opencv 4 and newer cmake introduced that functionality, and now it is a preferred way. But back to 2015 (or for older versions) it does not work.